# Tag Property Length

Tags: c#, wpf

What is maximum lenght of the Tag property of the control

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not how it works, the Tag property type is System.Object.  You can store a reference to anything you want, including a 2 gigabyte string on a 64-bit version of Windows.

Answer (score 3):

There is none, it takes an [object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx).